Oracle Autonomous Database access works in curl but not in c#
I am struggling implementing Oracle json DB.
When I run this:
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer VFQzfKCN0C1wkqyxTAR3yw" 
     -X GET https://xxxxxx-yyy.adb.eu-stockholm-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/peka/soda/latest/

it works as expected, without any problems.
When implementing the same function in C# code I get:

DB Error: Unauthorised"

I know the access token works as it is the same I use in the above curl.
Here is the code:
using Unity.Services.CloudCode.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ReadPlayerRecord;

public class MyModule
{
    public string url = "xxxxxx-yyy.adb.eu-stockholm-1.oraclecloudapps.com";
    public string clientId = "zzzzz";
    public string clientSecret = "mmmm";

    private string? msg;
    public AccessToken? accessToken;

    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    [CloudCodeFunction("ReadPlayerRecord")]
    public async Task<string> ReadPlayerRecord()
    {
        msg = ">>ReadPlayerRecord<<\n";
        await GetAccessTokenAsyncAndReadJson();
        return msg;
    }

    public async Task GetAccessTokenAsyncAndReadJson()
    {
        msg += ">> GetAccessToken <<\n";

        var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clientId + ":" + clientSecret);
        var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                });

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://" + url + "/ords/peka/oauth/token", formContent);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var resultContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                accessToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessToken>(resultContent);

                msg += "\nAccessToken: " + accessToken?.access_token + "\n";
                msg += ">> SODA <<\n";

                Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken?.access_token;
                msg += "https://" + url + "/ords/peka/soda/latest\n"; //fruit\n";
                var urlResponse = await client.GetAsync("https://" + url + "/ords/peka/soda/latest"); //"/fruit");

                if (urlResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var urlResultContent = await urlResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    msg = urlResultContent;
                }
                else
                {
                    msg += "DB Error: " + urlResponse.StatusCode + "\n";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                msg += "Access Token Error: " + response.StatusCode + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class AccessToken 
{
    public string? access_token { get; set; }
    public string? token_type { get; set; }
    public int? expires_in { get; set; }
}

Here is the output:
RESPONSE: _jsonResult: >>ReadPlayerRecord<<
>> GetAccessToken <<
AccessToken: VFQzfKCN0C1wkqyxTAR3yw
>> SODA <<
https:// xxxxxx-yyy..adb.eu-stockholm-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/peka/soda/latest
DB Error: Unauthorized

Would anyone nice be able to help me figure out what is wrong with my C# code as it works using curl?

The code never uses the token in client.GetAsync(). It stores it in the headers dictionary but never uses it

Holy sh.. what a mistake. Thank you @Panagiotis Kanavos. Please post as an answer and I accept it. BIG Thank you.
